# How to create Bubble map

Tags: php, drupal

I want to make Bubble type map in <kbd>Drupal</kbd> for particular hierarchy like below.

```
     engineer
        |
     testing  
     |     |
 manual   Software
     |        |
 testing   testing
```

*Is there any other structure  for make hierarchy?*

Data should be display dynamically in hierarchy manner and design should be good..

Comment: http://jpgraph.net/features/gallery.php#balloon1

Answer (score 0):

Tags and menus have tree structure as you need. Maybe you can use some of those?
Or do a custom hierarchy by using node reference field type. I.e. every node of your content type would have some "Parent" field of node reference type..